# Qbasic code to solve for the permutation of a given number

Tags: qbasic

Write a QBASIC to Solve find the permutation of a given numbers.
I've tried this in a Qbasic compiler

```
Input n
Input r
P = n! / (n - r)!
Print p
```

Comment: QBASIC does not have a built-in operator for factorials (`n!`); you'll have to implement that yourself first.

Comment: QBasic is interpreted not compiled

Comment: How am I going to implement that??

Comment: factorials should be simple to implement:

function factorial(a) : for n = a to 2 step -1 : f = f * (a-1) : next n : factorial = f : end function  '... or something like that...

Comment: Your question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205306/is-there-a-special-formula-for-permutation/61158325#61158325

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a special formula for permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205306/is-there-a-special-formula-for-permutation)

Answer (score 0):

Like AKX recommended, I've written a factorial function.

```
Input n

Input r

P = fact(n) / fact(n - r)

Print P

Function fact (n As Integer): 'factorial function
    o = 1
    Do While n > 1:
        o = o * n
        n = n - 1
    Loop
    fact = o
End Function
```