# Is there a special formula for permutation

Tags: string, factorial, qbasic

Who can help me out with a QBASIC CODE to find the permutation of a given number.
I'd really appreciate.
I've tried writing some codes but it's not giving the required answer.

Comment: Hi there! You should put the question you'd like answered in your question. Simply asking who can help isn't useful since we're all here to help! :)

Comment: Then help me out pls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qbasic code to solve for the permutation of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148215/qbasic-code-to-solve-for-the-permutation-of-a-given-number)

Comment: Please, insert your "better" code in the question! We can better understand your question and we might correct your code issues.

Answer (score 0):

If by permutation you mean the factorial then the following is the code that you need.
It will get an integer and compute its factorial.

```
DECLARE FUNCTION Factorial (n)
FUNCTION Factorial (n)
  IF n = 0 THEN
    Factorial = 1
  ELSE
    Factorial = n * Factorial(n - 1)
  END IF
END FUNCTION
INPUT "PLEASE ENTER AN INTEGER", n
PRINT n;"! = "; Factorial(n)
```

But if by permutation you mean all of the permutations of the sequence 1,...,n then it is another story. So let me know in the comments.